# Attach a jquery event after object is created

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, bpopup

I am using the bPopup jquery library.. the syntax to add to the onclose event is pretty straightforward:

```
$('element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
     onOpen: function() { alert('onOpen fired'); }, 
     onClose: function() { alert('onClose fired'); }
})
```

What I want to do is add something to the onClose event after the object is created.. is it possible?

Comment: Unless the plugin has methods to add stuff later, it's not possible, the object is passed in when the instance is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `bPopup` object which will be present inside the `data` of the element.

```
$('element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
    onOpen: function() { alert('onOpen fired'); }, 
    onClose: function() { alert('onClose fired'); }
});

$('element_to_pop_up').data('bPopup');
```

**NOTE:** There is no guarantee that the created object will be always present in element's data. But this is widely used approach. It is better to rely on the callback provided.

Comment: I like this approach.. why would there be no guarantee that the object will be on the data? Isn't there where it's always supposed to be?

Comment: @RaphaelCabrera Yeah, the object should be present in the data. Again, it depends on the plugin developer. If the developer didn't persist the object in element's data then you can't access it. Since this is widely used approach in jQuery plugins, you can rely on it.

Answer (score 2):

In general you can do this by creating a function that you fiddle with later:

```
var myOnClose = function() { alert('onClosed fired'); }
function doOnClose() { myOnClose(); }

$('element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
    onOpen: function() { alert('onOpen fired'); }, 
    onClose: doOnClose
})

// later...
myOnClose = function() { console.log("Doing something different!"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var realOnclose = f1;
function myOnClose(){realOnclose();}
 $('element_to_pop_up').bPopup({ 
    onOpen: function() { alert('onOpen fired'); },
    onClose: myOnClose
})

function f1() { alert('onClose fired'); } 
function f2() { alert('hey I am another function'); } 

//when you want to change the action when onclose...
realOnclose = f2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add to, rather than replace, the code you originally supply to the `onClose` option, you could trigger a custom event:

```
$('element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
    onClose: function() {
        // Do the original stuff here.
        this.trigger('popup:close');
    }
});
```

Then, at any time later, you can register a handler for the custom event:

```
$('element_to_pop_up').on('popup:close', function() {
    // Do the additional stuff here.
});
```

Note: Looking at the code for the bPopup library, it looks like the context for the `onClose` function is the original jQuery object, but if it isn't, replace with: `$('element_to_pop_up').trigger('popup:close');`.